# Clipping child QGraphicsItems

Tags: qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsItem` that contains several other `QGraphicsItems`.

How can I ensure that those children items are drawn and clipped against parent item's rect when moving them?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape, true);
```

More information can be found at:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum

Comment: +1: Of course this assumes that the parent item's `shape()` is still using the default of returning the bounding rectangle.